# Parsing HTML with VB DOTNET

Tags: html, vb.net, parsing, html-parsing, web-crawler

I am trying to parse some data from a website to get specific items from their tables. I know that any  tag with the bgcolor attribute set to #ffffff or #f4f4ff is where I want to start and my actual data sits in the 2nd  within that .

Currently I have:

```
Private Sub runForm()


    Dim theElementCollection As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("TR")
    For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
        Dim controlValue As String = curElement.GetAttribute("bgcolor").ToString
        MsgBox(controlValue)
        If controlValue.Equals("#f4f4ff") Or controlValue.Equals("#ffffff") Then

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This code gets the TR element that I need, but I have no idea how (if it is possible) to then investigate the inner  elements. If not, what do you think would be the best route to take? The site does not really label any of their tables. The 's i am looking for basically look like:

```
<td><b><font size="2"><a href="/movie/?id=movieTitle.htm">The Movie</a></font></b></td>
```

I want to pull out "The Movie" text and add it to a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `InnerHtml` property of the `HtmlElement` object (`curElement`) you have, like this:

```
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
    Dim controlValue As String = curElement.GetAttribute("bgcolor").ToString
    MsgBox(controlValue)
    If controlValue.Equals("#f4f4ff") Or controlValue.Equals("#ffffff") Then
        Dim elementValue As String = curElement.InnerHtml
    End If
Next
```

Read the documentation of [HtmlElement.InnerHtml Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.innerhtml.aspx) for more information.

UPDATE:

To get the second child of the `<tr>` HTML element, use a combination of `FirstChild` and then `NextSibling`, like this:

```
For Each curElement As HtmlElement In theElementCollection
    Dim controlValue As String = curElement.GetAttribute("bgcolor").ToString
    MsgBox(controlValue)
    If controlValue.Equals("#f4f4ff") Or controlValue.Equals("#ffffff") Then
        Dim firstChildElement = curElement.FirstChild
        Dim secondChildElement = firstChildElement.NextSibling

        ' secondChildElement should be the second <td>, now get the value of the inner HTML
        Dim elementValue As String = secondChildElement.InnerHtml
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. My only problem now is that I am still one layer too high. I am getting all of the <td> elements rather than just the second one. I could always do a substring after finding the location in elementValue of the second <td>, but that would be sloppy. Any idea of how to get the second <td> of the curElement?

Comment: See `UPDATE:` in my answer.

Comment: That worked perfectly. By using Dim elementValue As String = secondChildElement.InnerText rather than InnerHtml I was able to extract "The Movie" Text just like I needed. I would vote as useful, but since I had to make a new account I cannot yet. Haha. Have a great day!

Comment: I will try to remember to come back!