# Get content from table by webbrowser?

Tags: html, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I have the following table.

```
<table class="table1">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>SEQ</th>
                    <th>LOGIN</th>
                    <th>WHATSAPP</th>
                    <th>E-MAIL</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">1</a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/"></a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">name</a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">99 999999999</a></td>
                    <td><a href="http://www.google.com/">xxxxxxx@hotmail.com</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I would like to know how to get content from each TR to write to Access Database.

Because until the moment I only managed to get to this code.

```
Dim PageElement As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("table")
        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElement
            If (CurElement.GetAttribute("className") = "table1") Then
                TextBox1.Text = CurElement.InnerHtml

            End If
        Next
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406357/parsing-html-with-vb-dotnet

Comment: @JoshPart This is an issue in the table that has no class, id, or name.

Comment: Did you check HtmlAgilityPack? The next URL is applied to C# but you can get an idea of the purpose of HAP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack